# how do I disable a button on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function disableEnableButton(enable) {
    $('.register').prop('disabled', enable);
    $('.login').prop('disabled', enable);
    $('#instagram-login-btn').prop('disabled', enable);
    $('#register_submit').prop('disabled', enable);
    $('#login_submit').prop('disabled', enable);
}


$('#instagram-login-btn').on('click', function (event) {
    //disable all the other buttons
    disableEnableButton(false);

});
```

I am basically trying to disable all the other buttons when the state is loading.. so I use the jQuery prop to do so. However when it is loading and I click on instagram-login-btn, it still goes into the on('click') event. How do I do so?

Comment: For a user with nearly 4000 rep this is a lame question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `FALSE` in argument that means you are setting disabled property to `false` meaning `button` will not be `disabled` instead pass true as argument.

```
disableEnableButton(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#buttonID").attr("disabled", true);
```

call this.

Comment: No need to warp true in `""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').disabled='true';
```

call this on click event

Comment: I wanted to use jQuery

Comment: when normal javascript providing you the way, then why you want to use jquery way.

Comment: or this    $('#someid').attr('disabled', 'true');

Answer (score 0):

You can disable element by using

```
$("buttonID").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the disable attribute to the particular button

Try

```
$('#buttonID').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can element disabled by:

```
 $('#buttonID').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

OR

```
 $('#buttonID').attr("disabled", true);
```

For Example :

but I think, in your case you can directly `unbind` click event

```
$('#instagram-login-btn').click(function(){
        $('#instagram-login-btn').unbind( "click", handler );        
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/7GruF/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit_id').prop('disabled', true);
```